# Handling addError(String) from Managed package

Tags: apex

There is an addError(String) executed from a managed package.
How should this be handled by the code of the installed org?

This is the flow:
VF page->Controller--> update --> Managed package trigger->Managed package trigger utility> addError(String).
This addError is not propagating to the installed org.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

By "Not Propogating to the installed org", do you mean that you are unable to see what the error is for these items?

If so i would suggest overriding the managed VF page with a replica of your own extending the same controller and displaying the pageMessages

```
<apex:pageMessages />
```

tag on your page.

If the code in the controller was not designed to catch the errors - you would need to patch that so that you could capture and relay that to your page either by overriding a managed controller and writing it to the error block on your page by adding the error you have caught in your error handler OR modify your managed code to write this out properly. Managed code should still display an error on an object - the code and debug lines are more of what is protected here and withheld from those without access to managed code.